# Enabling background audio in my Windows Store HTML5 app

Tags: audio, windows-store-apps, html5-audio

I have an HTML5 Progressive Web App (PWA) that [I've packaged into the Window Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/chavah/9nhkjb6lpptv) thanks to [PWABuilder](https://www.pwabuilder.com/). It's a Pandora-like music app that plays audio via the HTML5 audio tag.

The app works fine on Windows 10 until **I minimize the app, then the audio stops playing.** I want my app to keep playing audio even when minimized.

My first thought is I need to declare the appropriate capabilities in my app manifest. So, in [my appxmanifest.xml](https://github.com/JudahGabriel/Chavah/blob/master/Chavah.Windows10/PWA/Store%20packages/windows10/manifest/appxmanifest.xml#L55), I added:

```
<Capabilities>   
   <uap3:Capability Name="backgroundMediaPlayback" />
</Capabilities>
```

But even with the backgroundMediaPlayback capability, it doesn't work; minimizing the app stops the audio.

Looking at the [Universal Windows audio sample app](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundMediaPlayback), it says this should work:

> "Adding the backgroundMediaPlayback capability enables all media
>   playback APIs become background enabled. That means you can use any
>   platform audio APIs, such as MediaPlayer, AudioGraph, XAudio2, **and
>   the HTML Audio tag.**"

If I'm reading that right, it means simply adding the backgroundMediaPlayback capability should make my HTML5 audio tags work in the background. **Is there something else I'm missing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the app is being suspended instead of using the `Activity Sponsored Execution` mode that's available for apps that declare the `backgroundMediaPlayback` capability ([MS blog here](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/06/07/background-activity-with-the-single-process-model/)).

Check to see if your app is being suspended when it's minimized.
Were you able to get the sample working?

**UPDATE 1**

It looks like your MinSDK and Target SDK are set to 10240 (the first version of Windows 10). Update the values to the following:

`<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.14393.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.16299.0"/>`

**UPDATE 2**

In addition to the SDK versions, you also need to add the **[SystemMediaTransportControls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.SystemMediaTransportControls)**. See the 2nd bullet point in under the "Requirements for Background Audio" paragraph in [this documentation article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/background-audio#requirements-for-background-audio).

Resources

I tracked down the different documentation articles that piece this together.

- In the [Background Audio article's Single Process section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/background-audio#explanation-of-one-process-model) defines the SDK version constraints as min version 1607 (aka Anniversary Update, OS Build/SDK 14393)
- The [UAP3 Capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-uap3-capability-manual) manual
- [Play Media In The Background](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/background-audio) documentation
- The [Manifest schema changes documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/what-s-changed-in-windows-10) (per release)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer. That MS blog you linked to says apps that want to use background media playback only need to "add the new background media playback capability to your manifest along with the new uap schema namespace, and that’s it." I've already done that. And yeah, the sample works on my Win 10 machine, but it doesn't use HTML5 audio tag, so it's not really a good test.

Comment: I did review your repo's manifest and everything looks good there. As far as the test it was to eliminate any machine-specific problems. I'm asking around MS internally to see if this is a known issue.

Comment: I noticed that your SDKs are set to 10240, I'm pretty sure Single Process can't go further back than Anniversary Update. Change to the following https://www.screencast.com/t/BR5jdpYIYO

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thank you!

Comment: I'll try that today. For the time being, I'm marking yours as the answer. Thank you!

Comment: I updated my answer with the actual manifest XML that should be used for the platform targets. Let me know how it goes, so I can inform my MS peeps that the case was solved :)

Comment: Hi Lance, I've updated my app and published to the Windows Store. It is still rolling out to the store - I will let you know as soon as I find out.

Comment: Excellent! FYI I spoke with some folks at Microsoft, they're going to update PWABuilder so that it defaults to at least 14393.

Comment: No luck! The updated app is in the app store, with the updated TargetDeviceFamily: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/chavah/9nhkjb6lpptv I uninstalled my old version, installed the new one, but it still goes silent when minimized. :-(

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link, I tested it and can reproduce as well. I'll forward this conversation internally to see what else might be the problem.

Comment: Have an answer for you. It's because of the missing transport controls (these are needed so that the user can pause/play/previous/next). I'll update my answer with the info.

Comment: Disappointing that my web app has to do that, but I can try, assuming SystemMediaTransportControls are available through WinJS.

Comment: Found an example https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/dev/Samples/SystemMediaTransportControls/js

Comment: Lance, I just tested this in my live app...and it works! THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU! I will roll out a final version of my app that has fully implemented.

Comment: Side note: I'd suggest the WinJS team add the following feature: for hosted web apps in the Windows Store, automatically hook up the navigator.media state to SystemMediaTransportControls. They do basically the same thing. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/media-session#set_metadata